# What functional technique enables not having to pass configuration through functions

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming

As I'm delving more into FP, I'm curious about the 'best' way to store settings that are loaded from config files. I've just been creating a case class with all the necessary config variables and setting that on app start. I then pass that case class into whatever function requires info from it.

However, it seems quite annoying especially when that settings case class has to propagate through many functions. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just add config as an implicit parameter for every method that needs it. You could also take a look at [reader monad](https://medium.com/@AyacheKhettar/using-cat-data-reader-monad-d70269fc451f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Reader`](https://richashworth.com/post/functional-design-patterns-in-scala-monads/#the-reader-monad) monad provides a way of propagating configuration without having to pass it as a parameter throughout all functions that need it. Contrast the following two implementations:

#### Config available from context via `Reader[Config, String]`

```
object ConfigFunctional extends App {
  case class Config(username: String, password: String, host: String)

  def encodeCredentials: Reader[Config, String] = Reader { config =>
    Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(s"${config.username}:${config.password}".getBytes())
  }

  def basicAuth(credentials: String): Reader[Config, String] = Reader { config =>
    Http(s"${config.host}/HTTP/Basic/")
      .header("Authorization", s"Basic $credentials")
      .asString
      .body
  }

  def validateResponse(body: String): Reader[Config, Either[String, String]] = Reader { _ =>
    if (body.contains("Your browser made it"))
      Right("Credentials are valid!")
    else
      Left("Wrong credentials")
  }

  def program: Reader[Config, Either[String, String]] = for {
    credentials       <- encodeCredentials
    response          <- basicAuth(credentials)
    validation        <- validateResponse(response)
  } yield validation


  val config = Config("guest", "guest", "https://jigsaw.w3.org")
  println(program.run(config))
}
```

#### Config passed in as an argument

```
object ConfigImperative extends App {
  case class Config(username: String, password: String, host: String)

  def encodeCredentials(config: Config): String = {
    Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(s"${config.username}:${config.password}".getBytes())
  }

  def basicAuth(credentials: String, config: Config): String = {
    Http(s"${config.host}/HTTP/Basic/")
      .header("Authorization", s"Basic $credentials")
      .asString
      .body
  }

  def validateResponse(body: String): Either[String, String] = {
    if (body.contains("Your browser made it"))
      Right("Credentials are valid!")
    else
      Left("Wrong credentials")
  }

  def program(config: Config): Either[String, String] = {
    val credentials = encodeCredentials(config)
    val response    = basicAuth(credentials, config)
    val validation  = validateResponse(response)
    validation
  }

  val config = Config("guest", "guest", "https://jigsaw.w3.org")
  println(program(config))
}
```

Both implementations should output `Right(Credentials are valid!)`, however notice how in the first implementation `config: Config` is not a method parameter, for example, contrast `encodeCredentials`:

```
def encodeCredentials: Reader[Config, String]
def encodeCredentials(config: Config): String
```

`Config` appears in the return type instead of being a parameter. We can interpret this as meaning

> "When `encodeCredentials` runs in the context that provides a
> `Config`, then it will produce a `String` result."

The "context" here is represented by `Reader` monad.

Furthermore, notice how `Config` is not a parameter even in the main business logic

```
def program: Reader[Config, Either[String, String]] = for {
  credentials       <- encodeCredentials
  response          <- basicAuth(credentials)
  validation        <- validateResponse(response)
} yield validation
```

We let the methods evaluate in the context containing `Config` via `run` function:

```
program.run(config)
```

To run above examples we need the following dependencies

```
    scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.6.0", 
      "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.4.1"
    )
```

and imports

```
import cats.data.Reader
import java.util.Base64
import scalaj.http.Http
```